# Get the application active by code

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I need to know the application that is being used by the user.
I want to make a lightning component that shows a page layout according to the application (by standard it is not possible). The component lightning will load a different page layout by app, showing in each layout different fields (to be as dynamic as possible, the component will load an existing page layout, where it will be modified to see it in the component (and not have to modify the html code))

In summary:
I need load a different page layout by application (these different layouts can be loaded into the component, or must be "hardcode" field by field in the code)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Even if you are able to know the `app` in which it is loading, you need to use multiple `aura:if` to show relevant layout. Instead create 2 components and use them separately in each app. this will also be less complex

Comment: It's a good idea. How would you recommend showing the custom layout as dynamic as possible?

Comment: Didnt exactly understand what do you mean by `dynamic`. Can you modify your question [edit] in a more detail way

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question with more details

Comment: Layout has different contexts - flexipage layout, record page layout, etc. Can you please be more specific and also add screenshots/sample code if possible

Comment: Edited, sorry. With layout I meant page layout